# Kendo MVC grid Client Template pass string to controller in onClick

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using `kendo mvc grid` to display index of my customer table

This is my code looks like

```
@model IEnumerable<CRM.CustomerViewModel>
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@using System.Collections

<div class="kentoCustm" id="UsrGrid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CRM.CustomerAllViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Cu_Name).Title("Customer").Width(180);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Cust_Company).Title("Company");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Cust_Type).Title("Type");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Cust_AssignedTo_Name).Title("Assigned To");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Cust_Email).Title("Email");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Cust_MobilePhone).Title("Mobile Phone");

        columns.Bound(o => o.Cust_ID)
                         .Title("Action")
                         .Filterable(false).Width(100)
                                    .ClientTemplate(
                                     "<button type='button' onclick='Details(#= Cust_ID #)' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add'><span class='k-icon k-i-search'></span></button>"
                                     + "<button type='button' onclick='Delete(#= Cust_ID #)' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add'><span class='k-icon k-delete'></span></button>"
                                      ).Width(100);
    })
  .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 50 }).Refresh(true))
  .Sortable(sortable =>
  {
      sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
  })
  .Groupable()
  .Filterable()
  .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(300))
  .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Id(p => p.Cust_ID);
      })
      .Read(read => read.Action("Customer_Read", "Ajax"))
      )
  )

</div>


<script>
    function Details(x,z) {
        window.location.href = "/DetailsCustomer/"+ z +"/" + x;
    }
    function Delete(x,z) {
        window.location.href = "/DeleteCustomer/"+ z +"/" + x;
    }
</script>
```

This works good for now, In this code i have two buttons for `Details` and `Delete` and i am using `onclick` events to redirect them into corresponding pages.

```
<button type='button' onclick='Details(#= Cust_ID #)' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add'><span class='k-icon k-i-search'></span></button>
```

This is the Details button.

**What I want**

I want to pass the name of customer in on click. I am displaying name as `"Salute" + "FirstName" + "LastName"`, thats stored in `Cu_Name`. This is the property of `CustomerViewModel`.

**My controller function**

```
    public ActionResult Customer_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        //View model List
        List<CustomerViewModel> customerlist = new List<CustomerViewModel>();

        //GetAddressByVendorId Data from database using repository

        IList<Customer> customer = _customer.GetCustomer().ToList();

        foreach (var item in customer)
        {
            CustomerViewModel customerobj = new CustomerViewModel();

            customerobj.Cust_ID = item.Cust_ID;
            customerobj.Cust_AssignedTo = item.Cust_AssignedTo;
            customerobj.Cust_Company = item.Cust_Company;
            customerobj.Cust_Type = item.Cust_Type;
            customerobj.Cust_Email = item.Cust_Email;
            customerobj.Cust_MobilePhone = item.Cust_MobilePhone;

            // removing spaces in first name
            customerobj.Cust_FirstName = item.Cust_FirstName.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

            // creating display name as "Salute" + "FirstName" + "LastName"
            if (item.Cust_AssignedTo != null && item.Cust_AssignedTo != 0)
            {
                var user = _user.GetUserById(Convert.ToInt32(item.Cust_AssignedTo));
                if (user != null)
                {
                    customerobj.Cust_AssignedTo_Name = user.Usr_FirstName;
                }
            }
            customerobj.Cu_Name = item.Cust_Salute + " " + item.Cust_FirstName + " " + item.Cust_LastName;

            // add each customer to viewmodel list
            customerlist.Add(customerobj);
        }
        DataSourceResult result = customerlist.OrderByDescending(a => a.Cust_ID).ToDataSourceResult(request, pos => new
        {
            Cust_ID = pos.Cust_ID,
            Cust_AssignedTo = pos.Cust_AssignedTo,
            Cust_Company = pos.Cust_Company,
            Cust_AssignedTo_Name = pos.Cust_AssignedTo_Name,
            Cu_Name = pos.Cu_Name,
            Cust_Type = pos.Cust_Type,
            Cust_Email = pos.Cust_Email,
            Cust_MobilePhone = pos.Cust_MobilePhone,
            Cust_FirstName = pos.Cust_FirstName
    });
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I Changed my button like this by adding `Cust_FirstName` to on click,

```
"<button type='button' onclick='Details(#= Cust_ID #,#= Cust_FirstName #)' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add'><span class='k-icon k-i-search'></span></button>"
```

But I am getting error in my console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: prince is not defined
>      at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Index:1)

where `prince` is a customer `Cust_FirstName`.

[image]

**Note**

What i think is this error occurs because i didn't add `Cust_FirstName` in the view. But i don't want to display first name alone i want to pass Cust_FirstName to those functions.

I tried adding

```
 columns.Bound(o => o.Cust_FirstName).Hidden();
```

But the same error occurs.

Please Help me here. thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you need quotes around the #=CustFirstName# argument. Try: "<button type='button' onclick='Details(#= Cust_ID #,\"#= Cust_FirstName #\")' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add'><span class='k-icon k-i-search'></span></button>" you may have to play around with the order of the double or single quotes but your click function thinks that the name is a variable that holds a value instead of the literal name...

Comment: @BillRuhl that worked, add that as an answer and i will select it

Comment: And can you describe why it needed the quotes while in the ID parameter it didn't

Comment: Because Id is a number and name is a string. It gets translated to something like `Details(123,prince)`. It thinks `prince` is a variable.